# EasyStream and slf4j API Issue

Tags: java, frameworks, slf4j

I needed EasyStream available at sourceforge site and added the dependency in my application. My SLF4J-API used to work just fine but now it has a disagreement. The way am using code snippet is :

```
private final Map<?, ?> parentContext;
 MDC.setContextMap(parentContext);
```

For some reason i am getting a compile time error now with the message :

```
The method setContextMap(Map<String,String>) in the type MDC is not applicable for the argument Map<Capture#5of-?,Capture#6of-?>
```

kindly suggest how i can get ride of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that EasyStream depends on a different version of SLF4J than the one you're using. Having more than one of the same version of a dependency on one's classpath leads to all sorts of weird issues. Depending on what dependency management system you're using, you probably need to tell it to exclude the child slf4j-api dependency or perhaps override it. For example, in Maven, I'd use the [`<dependencyManagement>`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Management) system to force all dependencies to use the same version of slf4j-api. Perhaps if you edit your question with more details about the dependency management system you're using you can get a more specific answer, and details on how to check and prevent such problems in the future.